# Passing an array of uint32_t uids via adafruit BTLE

Tags: arduino, nfc, mifare, uint32-t, btle

I have an arduino sketch, that listens for RFID tags, and gets their uid's  and stores them in an array of `uint32_t`

This is an arduino_uno project with an [adaFruit BTLE](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1697) and as [adafruit NFC/RFID Shield](https://www.adafruit.com/products/789)

The array is initiated like so:

```
uint32_t items[]= { 0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Then in my loop();

I find an id like so:

```
success = nfc1.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);
        //
        Serial.println(success,DEC);
        if (success) {
          // Display some basic information about the card
          //Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
          //Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
          //Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
          nfc1.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);

          if (uidLength == 4)
          {
            // We probably have a Mifare Classic card ... 
            cardid = uid[0];
            cardid <<= 8;
            cardid |= uid[1];
            cardid <<= 8;
            cardid |= uid[2];  
            cardid <<= 8;
            cardid |= uid[3]; 
            Serial.print("Seems to be a Mifare Classic card #");
            Serial.println(cardid);
            BTLEserial.print(cardid);
          }
          Serial.println("");
        }
```

Not that that block of code prints out to the Serial Monitor this:

> Seems to be a Mifare Classic card  #347161076
>   Writing out
>   to BTLE: 0x31 0x36 0x38 0x38 0x34

But the BTLE app is seeing

> 16884

" as the cardid?

It seems obvious that this is do to some weird byte conversion on the uint32_tbeing handled by the `BTLEserial.print()` method.

As i find id's I am storeing up to six of them in the items array above. I would like to send that entire array via blue tooth to my device, as a comma separated string.

Please help convert this uint32_t to either a string or other object that can be handled by the BTLE

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using this method:

```
int radix =10;
char buffer[33];

char* getStringForUI32_T(uint32_t value){
     return ultoa(value,buffer,radix);

}
```